# How to reference one apps script file from another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple files in my apps script project. Some of them are library files that provide utility functions for a larger app. How can I import them into my main file?

For example, in Node, I would be able to import `update-cell-1.gs` and `update-cell-2.gs` into my `main.gs` file like this:

```
// update-cell-1.gs
export default function() {
   // code to update cell 1
}

// update-cell-2.gs
export default function() {
   // code to udpate cell 2
}

// main.gs
import updateCell1 from "update-cell-1.gs";
import updateCell2 from "update-cell-2.gs";

function main() {
  updateCell1();
  updateCell2();
}

main();
```

What is the equivalent in apps script?

When I try using module.exports, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

When I try using `export default`, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Comment: Take a look at [SpreadsheetApp.openFileById();](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=en#openById(String))

Comment: Are these files in one project? What's the issue in executing your plan? I don't see a problem here.

Comment: @Cooper That's how to open a sheet, not an apps script file. I've updated my question to be clearer.

Comment: @TheMaster I updated my question to be clearer, please take another look.

Comment: You can't import functions but you can include libraries in your App Script.  Say Lib1.  Then you would reference a function in a library as Lib1.function1.

Comment: How do I turn an apps script `.gs` file into a library?

Comment: @TheWizEd When I try to create a new "library" in the apps script editor, it says "You can look up libraries available to you by their ID" and requires an ID field. This suggests that I cannot just make any file into a library, but must use a set that is already defined for me, so it wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: Still don't understand the problem. The files are just for convenience. In reality, they're all one file. It's like all the script is one file. You can call any function in any file directly without exporting or importing.

Comment: See this article [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries).  You start with an Google App Script file.  Build your code.  Deploy and get its Id.  In the other file in the script editor add the library id.

Comment: If it is as @TheMaster says.  One file but multiple `gs` let call them tabs (files) then you can think of it as one big file.  Any function from any tab can be called by any other function in the same file.

Comment: @TheMaster thanks, that sounds like an answer. I did not know that, that was the problem. You assumed I did, so you did not understand the problem. That is not how JavaScript typically works. It's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) or js web frameworks, You can call any function in any file in the same script project directly without exporting or importing anything.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a script that backs up all of the files in a script project.

You can choose either separate files or all one JSON file. You can also select which files that you wish to save.

GS:

```
function saveScriptBackupsDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('backupscripts1'), 'Script Files Backup Dialog');
}

function scriptFilesBackup(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const scriptId = obj.script.trim();
  const folderId = obj.folder.trim();
  const saveJson = obj.saveJson;
  const saveFiles = obj.saveFiles;
  const fA = obj.selected;
 
  if (scriptId && folderId) {
    const base = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"
    const url1 = base + scriptId + "/content";
    const url2 = base + scriptId;
    const options = { "method": "get", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    const res1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options);
    const data1 = JSON.parse(res1.getContentText());
    const files = data1.files;
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

    const res2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, options);
    const data2 = JSON.parse(res2.getContentText());
    let dts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss");
    let subFolderName = Utilities.formatString('%s-%s', data2.title, dts);
    let subFolder = folder.createFolder(subFolderName);
    if (saveFiles) {
      files.forEach(file => {
        if (file.source && file.name) {
          let ext = (file.type == "HTML") ? ".html" : ".gs";
          if (~fA.indexOf(file.name)) {
            subFolder.createFile(file.name + ext, file.source, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
          }
        }
      });
    }
    if (saveJson) {
      subFolder.createFile(subFolderName + '_JSON', res1, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
    }
  }
  return { "message": "Process Complete" };
}

function getAllFileNames(fObj) {
  if (fObj.scriptId) {
    const base = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"
    const url1 = base + fObj.scriptId + "/content";
    const options = { "method": "get", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    const r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, options);
    const data = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
    const files = data.files;
    const names = files.map(file => file.name);
    return names;
  }

}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
        input {margin: 2px 5px 2px 0;}
    #btn3,#btn4{display:none}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="scr" name="script" size="60" placeholder="Enter Apps Script Id" onchange="getFileNames();" />
        <br /><input type="text" id="fldr" name="folder" size="60" placeholder="Enter Backup Folder Id" />
        <div id="shts"></div>
    <br /><input type="button" value="0" onClick="unCheckAll();" size="15" id="btn3" />
    <input type="button" value="1" onClick="checkAll();"size="15" id="btn4"/>
        <br /><input type="checkbox" id="files" name="saveFiles" checked /><label for="files">Save Files</label>
        <br /><input type="checkbox" id="json" name="saveJson" checked /><label for="json">Save JSON</label>
        <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="backupFiles();" />
    </form>
        <script>
      function getFileNames() {
        const scriptid = document.getElementById("scr").value;
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((names) => {
          document.getElementById('btn3').style.display = "inline";
          document.getElementById('btn4').style.display = "inline";
          names.forEach((name,i) => {
           let br = document.createElement("br"); 
           let cb = document.createElement("input");
           cb.type = "checkbox";
           cb.id = `cb${i}`;
           cb.name = `cb${i}`;
           cb.className = "cbx";
           cb.value = `${name}`;
           cb.checked = true;
           let lbl = document.createElement("label");
           lbl.htmlFor = `cb${i}`;
           lbl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${name}`));
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(cb);
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(lbl);
           document.getElementById("shts").appendChild(br);
          });
        })
        .getAllFileNames({scriptId:scriptid}); 
      }
      function unCheckAll() {
        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        console.log(btns.length);
        for(let i =0;i<btns.length;i++) {
          btns[i].checked = false;
        }
      }
      function checkAll() {
        let btns = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        console.log(btns.length)
        for(let i = 0;i<btns.length;i++) {
          btns[i].checked = true; 
        }
      }
      function backupFiles() {
        console.log('backupFiles');
        sObj = {};
        sObj.script = document.getElementById('scr').value;
        sObj.folder = document.getElementById('fldr').value;
        sObj.saveJson = document.getElementById('json').checked?'on':'';
        sObj.saveFiles = document.getElementById('files').checked?'on':'';
        sObj.selected = [];
        console.log("1");
        const cbs = document.getElementsByClassName("cbx");
        let selected = [];
        for(let i = 0;i<cbs.length; i++) {
          let cb = cbs[i];
          if(cb.checked) {
            sObj.selected.push(cb.value)
          } 
        }
        console.log("2");
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(obj){google.script.host.close();})
        .scriptFilesBackup(sObj);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(sObj));
      }
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

There maybe some helper functions that I'm missing let me  know.  I use this all of the time to backup my code.

A typical back up looks like this:

[image]